# How to make logos like attached examples?

Tags: logo, effects

i really love this kind of style for logos. These are simple yet catchy. I would really like to design these logos but whenever Ii try, I fail to give effect and outlining like the attached logos(mascot and complete logo). Can anybody tell me how can i give these effect and outlining(in illustrator or CorelDraw)?

NOTE: I'm using featured logos  from LogoPond.com, If i'm using your logo and you don't like it, I will immediately remove it!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm not really clear how this could be answered effectively. You may as well ask... "How do I paint masterpieces like Picasso?"

Answer (score 2):

The specifics of this style are:

- line art uses heavy weight lines
- line color is a deep shade of main colors in logo (as opposed to black)
- insides areas are filled in with flat areas of color, but multiple areas are used to create shadows and shading.

As for 'how to make them' you'd draw them, but then incorporate the above features into your drawing. If you have a specific question regarding any of those, do ask.

Comment: Yes, how to add these features clearly. I add them but the image and strokes doesn't look much good

Comment: @ahmed, it'd be useful if you showed an example design that you want to style like the above logos.

Comment: @Ahmed please update your question with examples of what you tried and what you feel isn't working for you.  We can then offer specific advice.

Answer (score 0):

Every logo starts with a good sketch. Once you have the inside part completed, then go to object > Path > Offset Path, and set the desired number of pixels you wish to offset. Sometimes the angels can get ... funky. At times like these there is no other workaround than to just hash out the details with the pen tool, and drag the handles until your satisfied.